# GTAV seems to be using shared video memory instead of dedicated vram . Can this be changed manually?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, vram

So I've been running this game for more than a month now and it was running smoothly on low settings for hours and at that time the in-game graphics settings showed I was using the 512 mb or 1024 mb (depending how much I allocate) VRAM mentioned below

Specs :

[image: Video memory details]

So the issue is that after a recent update the game started lagging a lot and having rendering problems so I went to the in-game settings to find this anomaly:
[image]

If you look at the top of the image it says:
**867mb/4047mb** which is actually the shared memory which I think is causing the problem .

Can someone please help me ? I was thinking of contacting Rockstar support but I think they'll probably say I need an Nvidia GPU or something but I doubt that's the problem as it's been running fine all this time before this happened.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't alone. Thousands of people are facing this same issue. I'm also suffering from this issue. Please [report it to Rockstar](https://support.rockstargames.com/). You can talk with them in live chat or submit a ticket to let them know about your issue.

The more people that report this issue, the more chances for us to get a patch fix quickly. Please don't hesitate. Contact them.